# After changing the observable's value, the view doesn't change

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a logic like this.

**component.ts**

```
this.program$ = this.programEntityService.entities$.pipe(
      map(programs => programs.find(program => program.id === this.program.id))
    );
    this.levels$ = this.levelEntityService.entities$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.program$),
      tap(console.log),
      map(([levels, program]) => levels.filter(level => level.programId === program.id)),
      tap(console.log)
    );
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let level of levels$ | async">
...
</mat-tab>
```

When I add a new level with ngrx dataService like this

```
this.levelEntityService.add(level)
```

I expect that the view will be changed in accordance with these changes.

But I have another result:

**ngOnInit -> console**

```
(2) [Array(93), {…}]
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

**after adding a level**

```
(2) [Array(94), {…}]
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

The whole number of levels has been increased, but the filtered result - not.

Comment: This shoulf mean that the added level program id match the program id of programEntityService.

Comment: @AshishRanjan The level.programId matches program.id. After reloading the page i can see this new level rendered.

Comment: On adding a level, should a new program be added too?

Comment: @AshishRanjan No. All the levels belong to this program. I create one more level and add it to the "level" entity. Then I filter all the levels by level.programId in order to display levels only from this program.

Comment: check the value of level that you add to in this.levelEntityService.add(level)

Comment: @DerekKite Hmm .. the value is ok. I can see it after reloading of the page. It appears ... but i expect it to appear at once like it is with delete method. Delete method works fine.

Comment: @DerekKite add method works fine. This level appears in the store. The problem is that the filter insile levels$ observable doesn't see it

Comment: does it have the proper id that the filter is looking for?

Comment: @DerekKite Yes. Because after reloading the page this level appears where it should be .. inside this program.

Comment: The problem seems to be within `levels.filter(...)` if the input length increases from 93 to 94 but the output is 14 both times. Add a `console.log` inside `levels.filter(...)` to see what's happening to your 94th level and why it's omitted.

Comment: @fridoo Thanks, I have found the reason and posted it s an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason of the issue.  All my IDs are of type number. But for some reason, the response from the DB turned it into a string. I have changed the filter in this way:

```
this.levels$ = this.levelEntityService.entities$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.program$),
      map(([levels, program]) => levels.filter(level => +level.programId === +program.id)),
    );
```

And now it works as expected.